# Run command from different server using ssh2_exec() - php

Tags: php, ssh, openssh

There are 2 servers (server A and server B). The server A will send a command and server B execute it.

I had try the below code running from server A to instruct server B do a job and it work successful:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('server.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

ssh2_exec($connection, 'mv /var/www/test.php /root');

var_dump($connection);
```

from the above code, it will move test.php to the root folder. The problem happen if I try running the .sh file using the same code, it seems not running at all. Below is my example code to run .sh file

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('serverB.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

ssh2_exec($connection, './var/www/bbb_clean.sh');

var_dump($connection);
```

If I run the bbb_clean.sh manually from the server B, it works . Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to use [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/), and enable logging to see what's going on.  eg.

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');
define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', NET_SSH2_LOG_COMPLEX);

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->getLog();
?>
```